# FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE / You cannot combine custom title with other title features

Tags: android

I have what seems to be a problem I can not solve.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // comments describe what happens
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  Boolean customTitleSupported = this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
  // crash at underneath line
  try
  {
    setContentView(R.layout.myactivity); 
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   // You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
  }
  // never gets to underneath line
  if customTitleSupported {
    this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.override_titlebar);
  }
}
```

...

I use the **android-support-v4.jar** library

**requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);** does not cause any problems.

...

From **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="8"
  android:targetSdkVersion="17"   
/>

<application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/replace__logo__app_256_256"
  android:label="@string/MicAppName"
  android:theme="@style/MicTheme"
  android:name="com.example.app.MicApp"
>
```

From **styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

From **my_theme_support.xml**

```
   <style name="MicWindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0px</item>
    </style>    
   <style name="MicWindowTitleTextAppearance">
       <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
       <item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>        
   </style>           
   <style name="MicWindowTitle">
     <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MicWindowTitleTextAppearance</item>
     <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
     <item name="android:shadowDy">0</item>
     <item name="android:shadowRadius">5</item>
     <item name="android:shadowColor">#1155CC</item>
   </style>
```

From **my_theme.xml**

```
   <style name="MicTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">             
     <item name="android:windowTitleSize">44dip</item>
     <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/MicWindowTitleBackground</item>
     <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/MicWindowTitle</item>          
   </style>
```

...

And finally **override_titlebar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
>                
<ImageView android:id="@+id/myTitleLogo" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/replace__logo__app_256_256">
>
</ImageView>    
<TextView     
  android:id="@+id/myTitleText" 
  android:text="@string/dotdotdot" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent"        
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I guess that `this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(...` has to go **BEFORE** setContentView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had missed I had a separate **styles.xml** for never Android phones which used

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
```

Replacing that with

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
```

has made it work